# The right way to reload and restart State Machine with different data set

Tags: spring-statemachine

I need the same SM to serve various records from the same db-table (can't create SM per each record). Would this be appropriate way to reinitialize SM with new states from another record OR can you advice a better approach please ?

```
    public static <S, E> void reinitStateMachine(Integer key, IStateMachineEnabledService sees, StateMachine<S, E> stateMachine, Class<? extends Enum> statesClazz) {
    String dbReadState;
    try {
        dbReadState = sees.findStateById(key);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MissingResourceException("Error while trying to load record with state, no record found: "+key+". Extra info:"+e.getMessage(),sees.toString(),String.valueOf(key));
    }
    S currentState = (S) Enum.valueOf(statesClazz, dbReadState);
    stateMachine.stop();
    ((AbstractStateMachine<S, E>) stateMachine).resetStateMachine(new DefaultStateMachineContext<S, E>(currentState, null, null, null));
    stateMachine.start();
}
```

Thanks !

PS: I am aware of persist and restore interfaces in 1.1.0, but persisting SMContext works only for string state machine, while i use enum.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what `AbstractStateMachinePersister` does, though it uses getStateMachineAccessor() to avoid casting and getting access to other regions(which you probably don't have). I need to check what's the issue with enums.

Comment: @JanneValkealahti Are you saying it's not good way to go? I'm facing the same problem, I'd like to use State Machine as some kind of a state router (e.g from this A state, go to B state). State machine would be stateless then, just like Petar's trying to do

Comment: Maybe bit of the topic, I ended up removing AbstractStateMachinePersister that I used before. Problem is that domain model and db constraints sometimes do not allow me to persist new state due to referential integrity (e.g. new record in db with the state "NEW" must have some other fields satisfied as well).

Now if you exclude persister recipe things get a lot easier, I ended up using state machine just as state machine, no persister. I do business functions that persist entity including the state; while state machine just decides if transition is allowed (flow, validators). Much simpler.